# having multiple strings but same argument

Tags: bash, shell

I want to be able to do something like

```
echo "Hello" + " " + "World" + "!"
```

But I don't know how to do it, what to search for, or if it actually works at all.

Comment: Why do you want to do that?  You can do `echo "Hello"" ""World""!"`, and it will concatenate the strings.   If you're thinking of concatenating variables to strings, you can do the same thing, or just put the strings right in the quotes.   Notice that echo will also echo the whitespace between the quotes as well...

Comment: @John THANKS! If you post it as an answer I will accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quotes don't define strings as they do in other languages. They simply escape whatever is between them, just as if you had used a backslash. `\h\e\l\l\o` and `"hello"` represent the exact same string, and both are equivalent to `hello` by itself.

Technically, there is no concatenation of strings, because a string needs to be explicitly split to produce multiple words. You can think of `"hello""world"` as "concatenating" two strings, but as far as the shell is concerned, there aren't two separate strings to start with, only two sets of quotation marks to remove.

So to answer your question, you would just write

```
 $ echo "Hello"" ""World""!"
```

or more simply

```
 $ echo "Hello World!"
```

or even (to quote the minimum necessary number of characters):

```
 $ echo Hello\ World!
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
echo "Hello World!"
```

or

```
var1="Hello"
var2=" "
var3="World"
var4='!'
echo "${var1}${var2}${var3}${var4}"
```

Why did I put `var4` in single quotes? The `!` has a special meaning. I could better use single quotes for all var's, but this way you can see that you must be careful with quotes.

Comment: A `!` by itself has no special meaning; `var4="!"` or even `var4=!` would have done the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
echo "Hello"" ""World""!"
```

and it will concatenate the strings. If you're thinking of concatenating variables to strings, you can do

```
echo "Hello"$VAR"WORLD"
```

or just put the strings right in the quotes:

```
echo "Hello${VAR}World"
```

Notice that echo will also echo the whitespace between the quotes as well... – 
John